# How do I get the PID of my main process (and not one of its workers)?

Tags: shell-script, centos, process, ps

I'm using CentOS 7.  I'm trying to write a script to start and stop a puma process but I can't figure out how to get the "master" PID, if taht is even the right term.  In the below command

```
[rails@server myproject_production]$ ps aux | grep puma
rails    15767  0.0  1.2 437904 13612 ?        Sl   17:20   0:00 puma 3.11.4 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000,unix:///home/rails/myproject_production/shared/sockets/puma.sock) [myproject_production]
rails    15779  0.6  7.6 1061248 80688 ?       Sl   17:20   0:05 puma: cluster worker 1: 15767 [myproject_production]
rails    15781  0.6  7.7 1061248 80876 ?       Sl   17:20   0:05 puma: cluster worker 2: 15767 [myproject_production]
rails    15785  0.6  7.4 1061964 78488 ?       Sl   17:20   0:05 puma: cluster worker 3: 15767 [myproject_production]
rails    15880  0.7  7.4 1059612 78592 ?       Sl   17:22   0:05 puma: cluster worker 0: 15767 [myproject_production]
rails    17106  0.0  0.1 112612  1064 pts/0    S+   17:33   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

The master PID is "15767".  If I kill that all the other puma processes will die.  How do I write a command to get taht into a script variable?

Comment: I naively assume you can grep for more text from that line of `ps`, why can't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pgrep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) instead of filtering the output from `ps`. I think in your case, `pgrep -f '^([^ ]*/)?puma '` will match the right process, but experiment a bit to make sure that you're getting what you want and no more.

Once you're satisfied that `pgrep` is finding the process you want to kill, replace `pgrep` by `pkill`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using ps as follow:

`ps -ef | grep puma | grep -v grep | grep -v cluster | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

Explaination:
**ps**: gives the process information
**grep**: filters on the string provided
**grep -v**: removes the one with matching records
**awk '{print $2}'**: returns the second item from the line
**xargs**: converts the input provided into arguments for the command that follows it